# Insert com PDO e INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tenho uma tabela pessoa que possui os campos nome, cidade e telefone e time_id. Também tenho outra tabela com nome de time e nela tenho um campo chamado meu_time, como posso fazer um INNER JOIN para cadastrar o time nesse tabela time mas na tabela pessoa no campo time_id receber o id correspondente?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO pessoa (nome, cidade, telefone) VALUES(:nome, :cidade, :telefone)";
$stmt = Parent::__construct()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':nome', $nome);
$stmt->bindParam(':cidade', $cidade);
$stmt->bindParam(':telefone', $telefone);
$stmt->execute()
```

Comment: Apenas uma dúvida porque não está claro na pergunta. Você está querendo usar `INNER JOIN` em um comando `INSERT`?

Comment: @Pagotti, acredito que seja um insert em duas tabelas

Comment: axo que ele quer buscar uma informação em uma tabela e usar ela... mas axo que ele vai ter que fazer um select

Comment: Exatamente, vou tentar explicar melhor. Tenho um formulário e por ele cadastro no banco o nome da pessoa, cidade, telefone e o time dela, mas eu não queria deixar o time na mesma tabela da pessoa, isso porque outras pessoas podem ter o mesmo time, ai ficaria mais organizado se as tabelas ficassem separadas

Comment: Pode colocar a estrutura das duas tabelas na pergunta pra saber se da pra usar o `LAST_INSERT_ID`?

Comment: O time eu digito pra cadastrar, mas caso ele já exista eu não queria criar outro cadastro com o mesmo nome de time, caso exista eu queria apenas usar o que já esta lá

Comment: A tabela se chama principal se chama usuario, ai dentro dela tenho a tabela pessoa e a tabela time

Comment: o time já esta cadastrado?

Comment: O time eu vou cadastrar junto na hora de cadastrar o usuário, mas eu não queria cadastrar o time no mesmo campo de pessoa

Comment: é que fica mais organizado separado e vou ter um controle maior sobre ele

Comment: Atualiza sua pergunta colocando esses detalhes e a estrutura da tabelas envolvidas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caso `time_id` já exista, vc faz um `INSERT` com `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO pessoa (
    nome,
    cidade,
    telefone,
    time_id
    ) 
VALUES (
    :nome,
    :cidade,
    :telefone,
    SELECT meu_time FROM tabela WHERE tabela.campo=pessoa.campo LIMIT 1
)
```

Mas caso não, então serão dois inserts e não da pra fazer dois inserts ao mesmo tempo em um unico statement, então vamos usar a `TRANSACTION` que possibilita isso:

```
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO tabela_time (coluna1,coluna2,coluna3,...) VALUES (valor1,valor2,valor3,...);
   INSERT INTO pessoa (nome,cidade,telefone,time_id) VALUES (:nome,:cidade,:telefone,LAST_INSERT_ID());
COMMIT
```

> [Referência sobre **TRANSACTION**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html)
>
> [Referência sobre **LAST_INSERT_ID()**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-insert-id.php)
>
> [Referência sobre **INSERT com SELECT**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: Só uma correção. Usa `BEGIN` ou então `START TRANSACTION`. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9JgDy59Bbu19TtcYgzja4j/0

Comment: @Pagotti, obrigado pela correção

Comment: Deu certo, amo vocês gente hehe

Answer (score 0):

Vocês podem me dar a ultima ajuda? eu decidi colocar mais uma tabela, dessa vez chamada selecao, mas ta dando erro:

```
"begin;
insert into time    (meu_time) values ('cruzeiro');
$time = last_insert_id();
insert into selecao (minha_selecao) values ('brasileira');
insert into pessoa  (nome, cidade, telefone, time_id, selecao_id) values ('Otavio', 'São Paulo', 'telefone', $time, last_insert_id());
commit;";
```